# How to have a item in a lazyvgrid to take up two columns space

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a lazyvgrid and I want to one item in it to take up two spaces, or two columns.
I've tried to make another lazyvgrid with two columns but the height was different and I want all buttons to have the same height

```
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns4) {
                // 1 to 3
                ForEach(1...3, id:\.self) { i in
                    Button {
                        
                    } label: {
                        CalcCustomNumButton(buttonText: "\(i)", buttonType: .number)
                    }
                }
                
                // X
                Button {
                    
                } label: {
                    CalcCustomNumButton(buttonText: "X", buttonType: .operatoor)
                }

                Button {
                    
                } label: {
                    CalcCustomHButton(buttonText: "0", buttonType: .number)
                }

            }.padding(5)
```

I'm trying to achieve something like the photo attached[image]